# Windows Service: How can i create multiple windows service as a multiple exe file

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have project name as `WindowsServiceTest`. This project having three services name as `Service1`, `Service2` and `Service3`. And i want to create each service as Separate, Separate installer.

I want like following `Service1.exe`, `Service2.exe` and `Service3.exe`.

Is it possible??

and

How??

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: When you create an install project for WindowsServiceTest you can choose the service. So what about having three install projects for WindowsServiceTest in the same VS solution?

Comment: Yes. But for my need, i have added the another one service.

Answer (score 0):

You can create services in the command prompt (make sure it's running as an admin). For each of your files use the `sc create` command to make it a Windows Service.

`sc create [service name] binPath=[path to exe]`

Comment: In the binPath all the files in to one file (WindowsServiceTest.exe), then how can create separate exe ??.

Comment: Just place them in different directories or make a copy of each and name them separately.